# Mule Datamapper streaming for Excel files

Tags: java, mule, filestream, esb, datamapper

I have an application which reads bulk dataset let's say > 50K products and I am passing this data as List to Datamapper to transform out to a Excel file. While processing I am getting exception like this.

```js
ERROR 2015-03-24 20:00:18,971 [SPREADSHEET_WRITER0_1] org.jetel.graph.Node: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
ERROR 2015-03-24 20:00:18,972 [DataMapperGraphWatchDog] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Graph execution finished with error
ERROR 2015-03-24 20:00:18,972 [DataMapperGraphWatchDog] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Node SPREADSHEET_WRITER0 finished with status: ERROR caused by: GC overhead limit exceeded
ERROR 2015-03-24 20:00:18,972 [DataMapperGraphWatchDog] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Node SPREADSHEET_WRITER0 error details:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize(Saver.java:1592)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.preEmit(Saver.java:1223)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emit(Saver.java:1144)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emitElement(Saver.java:926)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.processElement(Saver.java:456)
 at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.process(Saver.java:307)
 at or
..................
org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getKey(SharedStringsTable.java:130)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.addEntry(SharedStringsTable.java:176)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:345)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:315)
 at com.opensys.cloveretl.component.spreadsheet.formatter.d.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.opensys.cloveretl.component.spreadsheet.formatter.i.write(Unknown Source)
 at org.jetel.util.MultiFileWriter.writeRecord2CurrentTarget(MultiFileWriter.java:420)
 at org.jetel.util.MultiFileWriter.write(MultiFileWriter.java:297)
 at com.opensys.cloveretl.component.SpreadsheetWriter.execute(Unknown Source)
 at org.jetel.graph.Node.run(Node.java:465)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR 2015-03-24 20:00:52,634 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Data Mapper execution failed. (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException). Message payload is of type: Object[]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. GC overhead limit exceeded (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)
  java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder:64 (null)
2. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask:122 (null)
3. Data Mapper execution failed. (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.CloverEngineImpl:131 (null)
4. Data Mapper execution failed. (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException). Message payload is of type: Object[] (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageProcessor:135 (null)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:64)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:85)
 at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2075)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2015-03-24 20:00:52,661 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Data Mapper execution failed. (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException). Message payload is of type: Object[]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. GC overhead limit exceeded (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)
  java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder:64 (null)
2. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException)
  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask:122 (null)
3. Data Mapper execution failed. (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.CloverEngineImpl:131 (null)
4. Data Mapper execution failed. (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.exception.DataMapperExecutionException). Message payload is of type: Object[] (com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.processors.DataMapperMessageProcessor:135 (null)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:64)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:85)
 at sun.font.SunFontManager.findFont2D(SunFontManager.java:2075)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I tried to use stream option from Datamapper but I didn't get any luck with that as well. I am getting below exception while processing through streaming.

```js
org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\Export\16581\16581.xlsx
ERROR 2015-03-26 17:48:04,769 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///C:/Export/, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=connector.file.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=70d7949c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='ExcelFileWriter', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[sessionVars["batchID"]]/#[sessionVars["batchID"]].xlsx}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}. Message payload is of type: DataMapperPipedInputStream
Type                  : org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.util.DataMapperPipedInputStream@286259d2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Pipe closed (java.io.IOException)
  java.io.PipedInputStream:-1 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///C:/Export/, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=connector.file.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=70d7949c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='ExcelFileWriter', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[sessionVars["batchID"]]/#[sessionVars["batchID"]].xlsx}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}. Message payload is of type: DataMapperPipedInputStream (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:109 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
 at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(FileMessageDispatcher.java:84)
 at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:99)
 at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2627)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:101)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.endpoint.outbound.OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.process(OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.java:39)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:50)
 at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
 at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
 at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
 at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
 at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
 at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
 at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
 at org.mule.execution.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:69)
 at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:56)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilterin...
********************************************************************************

WARN  2015-03-26 17:48:04,780 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.02] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Interrupted node: BEAN_READER0
WARN  2015-03-26 17:48:04,780 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.02] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Interrupted node: FOREACH_OBJECT_TEMPLATE
WARN  2015-03-26 17:48:04,780 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.02] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Interrupted node: REFORMAT0
WARN  2015-03-26 17:48:04,780 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.02] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Interrupted node: SIMPLE_GATHER0
WARN  2015-03-26 17:48:05,080 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.02] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Interrupted node: SPREADSHEET_WRITER0
ERROR 2015-03-26 17:48:05,081 [DataMapperGraphWatchDog] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Graph execution finished with error
ERROR 2015-03-26 17:48:05,082 [DataMapperGraphWatchDog] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Node SIMPLE_GATHER0 finished with status: ERROR caused by: null
ERROR 2015-03-26 17:48:05,083 [DataMapperGraphWatchDog] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: Node SIMPLE_GATHER0 error details:
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
 at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(Unknown Source)
 at org.jetel.graph.Node.run(Node.java:462)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR 2015-03-26 17:48:05,087 [DataMapperGraphWatchDog] org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog: !!! Phase finished with error - stopping graph run !!!
ERROR 2015-03-26 17:48:05,093 [[VelocityMule_Export].connector.VM.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///C:/Export/, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=connector.file.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=70d7949c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='ExcelFileWriter', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[sessionVars["batchID"]]/#[sessionVars["batchID"]].xlsx}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}. Message payload is of type: DataMapperPipedInputStream
Type                  : org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.util.DataMapperPipedInputStream@286259d2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Pipe closed (java.io.IOException)
  java.io.PipedInputStream:-1 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///C:/Export/, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=connector.file.mule.default
  lifecycle=start
  this=70d7949c
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='ExcelFileWriter', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[sessionVars["batchID"]]/#[sessionVars["batchID"]].xlsx}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=true}. Message payload is of type: DataMapperPipedInputStream (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:109 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
 at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(FileMessageDispatcher.java:84)
 at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:99)
 at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2627)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:101)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.endpoint.outbound.OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.process(OutboundResponsePropertiesMessageProcessor.java:39)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:50)
 at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor$1.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:47)
 at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
 at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
 at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
 at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
 at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
 at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
 at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
 at org.mule.execution.TransactionalExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalExecutionTemplate.java:69)
 at org.mule.processor.EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(EndpointTransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:56)
 at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:47)
 at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilterin...
********************************************************************************
```

How can we use DataMapper for such a situation like writing large dataset to a File through datamapper.

Comment: can you provide us the XML configuration

Comment: Data Mapper is currently deprecated. You should try with DataWeave  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule4-user-guide/v/4.1/dataweave instead.